# Pasting a huge amount of text into vim is slow?

Tags: vim

Someone showed me how to do this before but I can't figure out what it was now.

I know about `:set paste` but this is not the problem.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that Vim keeps trying to redraw the screen while you paste. Maybe there's a way to temporarily disable updating of the screen.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane maybe `set lazyredraw`?

Comment: @FDinoff `lazyredraw` affects macros and commands, not typed text.

Comment: 1) how huge the text is? 2) did you paste to a buffer with some syntax highlighting? e.g. paste a big trunk of html codes to your current HTML buffer...

Comment: I'm on a mac and used `pbpaste > file.txt`.  I know this isn't vim specific, but was super fast

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Use `"*p` or `"*P` to paste from the system clipboard instantly.

Vim must be compiled with [`+clipboard`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#+clipboard) for this to work.

See [`:help clipboard`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html#clipboard) for more information.

Comment: If the `'*` register doesn’t work, you can also try [`"+`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#quote+). Paste from it with `"+p`.

Comment: how I am gonna compile vim with +clipboard ?

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, `sudo apt install vim-gtk` installs Vim with clipboard support! (found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347519/unable-to-copy-from-vim-to-system-clipboard#434994))

Comment: What is the difference between `"+` and `"*` ?

Comment: `"+` and `"*` are various registers used by vim. You can see the contents of all registers by using `:reg`

Comment: I wish I knew this since approx 10 years ago

Comment: @minseong It seems `"*` holds the "mouse selection" clipboard (what you paste with middle click on Linux), while `"+` holds the main clipboard (what you paste with Ctrl+C).

Answer (score 23):

This is a buffer flush-to-disk problem. Vim tries to keep your work safe and doesn't assume you can type several thousand characters per second. Read `:help swap-file` for some details on the buffering. The solution to your problem is this:

Turn off vim's swapfile either with:

```
vim -n <your file>
```

or from within vim before the paste:

```
:set noswapfile
```

See `:help swapfile` for more details.

Another option is to simply turn off the syncing to disk of the swap file with `:set swapsync=` but this option takes more keystrokes to undo and I'm lazy. :)

**Turning off swap is not safe for normal operations!** Immediately after the paste, either use `:set swapfile` or `:set swapsync=fsync` to revert back to normal behavior (though technically, normal behavior might have been *sync* and not *fsync*, check with `:set swapsync?` beforehand if you want to go this route).

Comment: I have `set noswapfile` in my vimrc but still pasting is slow, do I need to set something else too?

Answer (score 10):

In my experience `:set syntax=off` helps before pasting, see https://askubuntu.com/a/223061/240577 I've seen 'slow' behavior/high cpu usage with vim/gvim/mvim on osx, ubuntu, redhat and windows when pasting large blocks of content and syntax highlighting is on.

Answer (score 2):

I use `:read !xclip -o` in my vim document after I positioned my cursor to paste my copied text.

Could also be:

```
:read !xsel -b # X11
:read !pbpaste # On macos
:r !@xclip -o # :r as :read alias
```

Answer (score 0):

For some filetypes `:set syntax=off` makes no difference because the slowdown is caused by `foldexpr`. Setting an empty `foldexpr` makes pasting fast again.

Doing it manually is stupid (and slow!). Luckily vim supports [bracketed paste](https://vimhelp.org/term.txt.html#xterm-bracketed-paste) in many terminals and enables `paste` automatically, so it's possible to hook into that and temporarily disable `foldexpr`:

```
function! s:paste_toggled(new, old) abort
    if a:new && !a:old
        let b:saved_foldexpr = &foldexpr
        let &l:foldexpr = ''
    elseif !a:new && a:old && exists('b:saved_foldexpr')
        let &l:foldexpr = b:saved_foldexpr
        unlet b:saved_foldexpr
    endif
endfunc

augroup FastPaste
    autocmd OptionSet paste call s:paste_toggled(v:option_new, v:option_old)
augroup END
```

(source: https://github.com/liskin/dotfiles/blob/69ab04e64e001da90232eaf2c5856337d58c785f/.vim/plugin/fastpaste.vim)