# Why is vim so slow with copy/paste?

Tags: vim

I find myself copy-pasting text between editors a lot. Often with the result of SQL outputs that are usually about 10,000+ lines. I have never had a problem doing this -- usually it takes all of a second or two to paste it in. However, when I use vim, it takes about a minute to copy-paste in all that text, this is after settings `:set no paste`.

Is this supposed to happen in vim or is there some sort of setting I can change so this doesn't occur? I've tried `TextMate`, `TextEdit`, `VSCode`, etc, and vim is the only one with this issue related to copy-paste.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258561/pasting-a-huge-amount-of-text-into-vim-is-slow have you tried this ?

Comment: @Niloct perfect, `"*p` is great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pasting a huge amount of text into vim is slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258561/pasting-a-huge-amount-of-text-into-vim-is-slow)

Comment: The reason it's slow when pasting text with middle click or control+v is that Vim doesn't see the difference between the text you typed and text you're pasting, so it will run all the logic for indentation and such, which can be quite slow if you're pasting large amounts of text. Using `set paste` disables a lot of that, so it's faster, and with `"*p` Vim knows you're just pasting literal text, so no need to apply this logic. This is kind of a limitation of terminals (although there are some solutions, like "bracketed paste", but it's not universal).

Comment: In my case, pasting was slow due to a silent that was starting with `p`: `nmap <silent> pr <Plug>(coc-format)`. So whenever I attempted to paste, I think vim was waiting to see if I would type something else after that to see if it would match `pr` but after changing that to `fr` it solved my issue. Hope it helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `:set paste` instead.

Because `:set no paste` paste character per character and check if whether these character is matched with some key binding, some shortcut.